# Instrumentation test cases in groovy?

Tags: android, groovy, instrumentation

Can we write instrumentation test cases for an android application in Groovy?
If so , how ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to run `groovy` on `Android`.
Check:

- http://thediscobot.blogspot.com/2009/07/howto-run-groovy-on-android.html
- http://code.google.com/p/discobot/
- http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/issues/detail?id=49

You should check if you are able to run those test cases.

Comment: The above code seems to be still in development stage. Just has only 3beta versions released for linux. How about Windows? 
Is there any better way to define instrumentation testing in groovy for an android application??

Comment: @KK: I don't know that. Sorry :(